# Removing substring between two words including the words, which are repeating in a string

Tags: java

I have to remove substrings between two words from a string which are repeating in the string.

For example, for the input:

> People consider that cats and dogs are good friends but the fact is that dogs have got a problem with cats. Dogs always chase cats and bark at them.

I want the output:

> People consider that are good friends but the fact is that.and bark at them.

Here "cats" and "dogs" are repeating and I have to remove all the substring between "cats" and "dogs" including "cats" and "dogs".

Comment: Show us some code what you tried before. This is not a tutorial page. Instead ask for a specific question based on your code.

Comment: Please add the example code you have tried already. The StackOverflow community will then help you.

Comment: I've edited your question a little to make it a bit clearer what your expected output is, given the input. It wouldn't hurt to include a couple more examples if you can. For example, what should happen for inputs like "I like cats", or "I like dogs and cats", or "Cats foo cats bar dogs"? As others have said you will also need to show some code for people to help you with, rather than just asking for someone to do your homework for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework.

```
String temp = "People consider that cats and dogs are good friends but the fact is that dogs have got a problem with cats. Dogs always chase cats and bark at them.";


temp = temp.replaceAll("(cats)(.*)(dogs)", "");
System.out.println(temp);
```

This will not yet give you your solution as its case sensitive ;-)
But if you want to do regexes, this is the way to go

Comment: It's not giving the expected result. I made everything to lower case and got the below result when I executed it." People consider that  always chase cats and bark at them."

Comment: "people consider that  always chase cats and bark at them." - This is your result i guess? Maybe because now we only remove a combination of Cats with Dogs and everything between. The last cat doesnt have a dog to connect with...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
private static String getWithoutRepetitions(String sentence){
    String result = sentence;
    String[] allWords = (sentence.replaceAll(",", " ").replaceAll("\\.", " ")).split(" ");
    HashMap<String, Integer> pairs = new HashMap<>();
    for(String s : allWords){
        if(pairs.get(s) == null && s != null){
            pairs.put(s, 1);
        }else{
            pairs.put(s, pairs.get(s)+1);
        }
    }
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : pairs.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = (Integer) entry.getValue();
        if(value > 1){
            result = result.replaceAll(key, "");
        }
    }
    result = result.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
    return result;
}
```